# ehcache-terracotta-2.6.0.jar is corrupted?

Tags: java, maven, build, ehcache, terracotta

I'm using terracotta 3.7.0 and I recently deleted my entire .m2 dir, so I have to re-install it.
But the build is stuck with error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-cache: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-terracotta\2.6.0\ehcache-terracotta-2.6.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Does anyone know what might cause this?

UPDATED: when I delete the entire .m2 again, I get this error. NOT terracotta anymore, but maven-jar-plugin. I have a feeling something must've gone wrong with maven.

```
[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 (C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-jar-plugin\2.4\maven-jar-plugin-2.4.jar):error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginDescriptorParsingException: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for
```

And this too

```
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is 757a33a0a05930dd579796da4bb82a61f612f49a for http://archiva.openqa.org/repository/releases/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.jar
```

Does this ring any bell for anyone?

Comment: What happens if you try to open `C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\net\sf\ehcache\ehcache-terracotta\2.6.0\ehcache-terracotta-2.6.0.jar` with Winzip/Winrar/equivalent?

Comment: I am getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things could possibly cause this, including:

- The file you are trying to open does not exist.
- The file you are trying to open has the wrong permissions.
- The file is corrupted.

There are (obvious) things you could try to diagnose these.

It is also possible that some a maven config or repository issue is preventing maven from downloading the file.  But there should be something in the output to say that.

You could also try running the `mvn` command with verbose logging enabled; use `mvn --help` to list the command line options.

---

> Checksum validation failed, expected  but is 757a33a0a05930dd579796da4bb82a61f612f49a

That looks like you have managed to fetch a corrupt checksum.  Or more precisely, that the remote server gave you an error page when you attempted to fetch the checksum.

Comment: hey Stephen. Thanks for the reply. The file is there but I can't open it. It's a jar file. Whenever I try, it'll say invalid or corrupted jarfile.

Comment: @abcXYZ - Then delete it and download a fresh copy.

Comment: yep that's what i did and it turned out to be a disaster. Looks like the url to maven's archiva has been changed. All of the downloaded poms of the plugins turned out to be html with thing like "Are you looking for something...".

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. A lot of the URLs specified in my pom are dead links. I deleted my entire .m2, changed those links to point to some archiva that actually has those jar, and it worked.